# Angular input element autocomplete attribute value based on variable

Tags: angular, input, autocomplete

I have an input element in my HTML and I want to set the native autocomplete HTML attribute value based on a variable in my TS file in an Angular component.

```html
<input [autocomplete]="disableAutocomplete ? 'off' : 'on'">
```

ts:

```
disableAutocomplete: boolean;
```

I get an error in my HTML saying: "Property autocomplete is not provided by any applicable directives nor by textarea element".

How can I bind a variable value to this autocomplete attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
<input [attr.autocomplete]="disableAutocomplete ? 'off' : 'on'">
```

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding